# Omitting 0 after decimal point until another number

Tags: java, android, double, decimal, calculation

Im trying to get 2 decimals from an editText and make a calculation which calculates the code below

```
            valueKilo = Double.parseDouble(edit_txt_kilo.getText().toString());
            valueBoy = Double.parseDouble(edit_txt_boy.getText().toString());
            resulVKI = (valueKilo / (valueBoy * valueBoy));
```

As example in this part of code lets give the values valueKilo = 76 and valueBoy = 173. The result of the calculation is  0,00253934

I have to just print it as 25.39 
Is there a solution to omit the 0 after decimal point until another number comes, so that I can print it as 25.39

(Multiplying the number by 1000 and using the code new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(resulVKI) didn't worked)

Comment: What does *"until another number comes"* even mean?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing fine. But you just have to multiply by `10000` instead of `1000`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers , the problem is solved. 
It was my fault. I had to multiply it with 10000  instead of 1000.